# Group_by and filter inside group on specfic date

Tags: r, dplyr

Hello I have 2 date frames as follows:

DF1:

```
ID Date 
1  2016-1-31 13:00:01 
1  2016-1-31 17:00:01 
1  2016-2-31 13:00:01 
2  2016-1-31 13:00:01 
2  2016-2-31 13:00:01 
3  2016-1-31 13:00:01 
3  2016-2-31 13:00:01
```

DF2:

```
ID Maturity Date
1  2016-1-31 15:00:01 
2  2016-3-31 12:00:01 
3  2016-1-31 13:00:02
```

I want to get one date frame that has the data before maturity, this should be the answer:

```
ID Date
1  2016-1-31 13:00:01
2  2016-1-31 13:00:01 
2  2016-2-31 13:00:01 
3  2016-1-31 13:00:01
```

I used the following but I got an error, because the object length is different:

```
a <- df1 %>%
dplyr::group_by(ID) %>%
dplyr::arrange(Date) %>%
dplyr::filter(Date < DF2$Date)
```

Somebody has a solution? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to either `merge` or `match`...something like `left_join(df, df1, by = 'ID') %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(Date < Maturity_Date)` should do it

Comment: perfect! Was looking for the left_join, thanks a lot.